# Javascript cannot get Json key

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to get a Json from my server using Javascript. Here is the servers response:

```
{
  "AAT": [
    {
      "Header": [
        {
          "TimeStamp": "14.12.2016 10:28:27",
          "MessageID": "0201A",
          "ErrorCode": "0"
        }
      ],
      "Body": [
        {
          "ClientToken": "eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjoyLCJh"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

And I am trying to get `ClientToken` like this:

```
var json = JSON.parse(data);

// Get the ClientToken from the Json
var token = json['ClientToken'];
```

This worked once, but I don't get it to work again.
Hope someone can see my mistake

Thanks

Comment: `json.AAT[0].Body.ClientToken`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the structure of your JSON: `ClientToken` is inside `Body` that is an array that is inside `AAT` which is, itself, an array. In order to access `ClientToken`, you will first have to go through its parents:

```js
var data = '{   \n' +
'  "AAT": [  \n' +
'    {  \n' +
'      "Header": [  \n' +
'        {  \n' +
'          "TimeStamp": "14.12.2016 10:28:27",  \n' +
'          "MessageID": "0201A",  \n' +
'          "ErrorCode": "0"  \n' +
'        }  \n' +
'      ],  \n' +
'      "Body": [  \n' +
'        {  \n' +
'          "ClientToken": "eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjoyLCJh"  \n' +
'        }  \n' +
'      ]  \n' +
'    }  \n' +
'  ]  \n' +
'}  \n';

var json = JSON.parse(data);
var token = json.AAT[0].Body[0].ClientToken;
alert(token);
```

Comment: Well it is still "Undefined" :/

Comment: var token = json.AAT[0].Body[0].ClientToken Body element is also an array so you need to use an index to access it

Answer (score 1):

`ClientToken` is inside `AAT->Body` so you can access it through `AAT->Body`

```
var token = json.AAT[0].Body[0].ClientToken;
```

I have used `0` index if there are multiple objects inside `AAT` and `Body` you will need to loop through `objects` to access `ClientToken`

Comment: This works, thanks!! But there is still one question: Why has this worked but suddenly it stopped?

Comment: What do you mean by it has stopped ?

Comment: Maybe the returned JSON used to be different?

Comment: like I said this worked once, and I didn't change the structure of my json, nor did I change the reading code for it